# How to get the least element from the values of a key in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose i have following Json object.

```
{
    "orderId": ["80055517"],
    "orderItemId": [
        "850057658",
        "850057657",
        "850057656"
        ]
}
```

Now i want the least value i.e 850057656 from orderitemId.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you do not have `orderItemId` sorted. You can get the result using following.

```js
var obj = {
    "orderId": ["80055517"],
    "orderItemId": [
        "850057658",
        "850057657",
        "850057656"
        ]
};

console.log(obj.orderItemId.sort()[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {
    "orderId": ["80055517"],
    "orderItemId": [
        "850057658",
        "850057657",
        "850057656"
    ]
};

alert(a.orderItemId[a.orderItemId.length-1]);
```